# Decimal math wrong result

Tags: android, math

I am trying to make the math code. But I can't do it.

```
double x = z + ((z * (25.7 - (((z - 400) / 30) * 1.27))) / 100);
int d = (int) Math.round(x);
```

for example if z=910.
Real math result is, x =947.401,   d = 947 but it doesn't by this code.

Could you help me to solve.

Comment: probably should understand how you're manipulating the number as it looks like you are losing precision based on the way you're doing everything. You should learn about int truncation and precision of operations with respect to double.

Comment: If 'z' is integral you will loose precision in the expression (z -400)/30.

Comment: Thanks, you showed me the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Should Know How Precedence works in programming

- () high Precedence
- then / and *
- the - and +

In Your Problem

This Statement `z + ((z * (25.7 - (((z - 400) / 30) * 1.27))) / 100)` Will Execute as

```
let z = 910

(z - 400) // result 510
then this (z - 400) / 30) // result 17
then this  (((z - 400) / 30) * 1.27))) // result 21.59
then this  (25.7 - (((z - 400) / 30) * 1.27)) //result 4.11 
then this  (25.7 - (((z - 400) / 30) * 1.27))) / 100) // result 0.2159
then this  ((z * (25.7 - (((z - 400) / 30) * 1.27))) / 100) // result 37.401
then this z + ((z * (25.7 - (((z - 400) / 30) * 1.27))) / 100) // final result 947.401
```

Then it will round off the `947.401` and give you `947`